# Decide if comment is a reply to another comment

Tags: css, wordpress, class, comments

I have searched Googled for this quite long now. I'm doing my own theme based on the Sandbox theme. Now I have come to the comment-section.

The Sandbox theme doesn't add nested comment (if the comment is a reply to another comment). Which makes the comment part a bit messy to figure out which is a reply to another comment or not.

Is there any CSS class I can add to my `comment.php` file to print out a certain CSS class if the comment is a reply or not? This because I want the reply to be indented from the left a bit under the comment it is an reply to.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use firebug to check the source of the template and see if there are any extra classes. If not, You should check if a comment has a parent in your comment loop and change/add the class there.

```
<?php 
$comments = get_comments($post_ID);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
   if ($comment->comment_parent>0) {
      echo('<div class="comment subcomment">'.$comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content.'</div>');
   } else {
      echo('<div class="comment">'.$comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content.'</div>');
   }
endforeach;
?>
```

And then just style the class trough css.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress function `comment_class()` adds a variety of classes, one of which is "comment depth." On the styling front, it tells you if it's a reply to another comment.

If you need to know for programmatic reasons, @pycior's answer should do the trick.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments . Just write the PHP code and your comments will appear on your page nested, and then you can make you own CSS so it will look the way you want.